# Excel 2003- Rows Limitation

Tags: excel

We have a Excel 2010  file that has 70000 rows and we need paste it in a file that is in Excel 2003 version.

it will normally not accept such amount of rows. any idea how it can be done?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4):

You can't.  But you can paste your rows in an Access database, and use the data menu in Excel to load subsets of your data (using `Data`, `Import external data`, `Database query`) or make a Pivot Table based on External data as well.
This will allow you to work with millions of rows if required.

Answer (score 1):

You have to split the rows over 2 worksheets in 2010, then you can copy/paste into 2003

Answer (score 1):

The maximum number of rows in Excel 2003 is 65,536, so you will need to either split it between two or more worksheets or use a pivot table to decrease the number of rows.  Depending on how granular the information is you might be able to achieve the desired result with less specificity.